# Can't find the DB security group in Amazon RDS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Not sure if Amazon recently removed DB security group.

Created a DB instance as shown below. But there is no DB security group tab on the left!
[image]

Back to the dashboard, it says I have 2 DB security groups. However I was redirected to the EC2 security groups when clicked it.

How can I create and configure the DB security groups now?

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After creating VPC the DB security group shows up in the RDS console. Indeed there are some changes Amazon made about the DB security group since Jan 2013.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html#Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.APIMigration

Comment: But what if you don't use VPC?