# Can't create DB security group on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm new to RDS and I'm trying to access a recently created MySQL database from my machine at work.  After some googling I saw that the DB Security Groups needed to be modified but I don't see that on my screen.  I continued searching and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214425/cant-find-the-db-security-group-in-amazon-rds-console) and it seems to be a step in the right direction but I'm still no understanding what it means by the "VPC" group.  I tried creating Parameter Groups, Option Groups, and Subnet Groups all to no avail.  I just need to give my work IP access to the DB.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
You can refer this blog post: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-RDS/2935

Comment: How can this be the right answer? The blog post doesn't even have the keyword 'security' in it...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RDS in a VPC, then you create / modify security groups in the AWS VPC console ([this link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#s=SecurityGroups)). If not, security groups for RDS are located in the AWS RDS console ([this link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-east-1#security%3a)). Those links assume you are on US East 1 region but can be modified for any region.

Comment: The "Security Groups" only shows up when selecting Virginia, not for other regions :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Security group from the VPC area. name it something like rds-webhostaccess Put in the ip block you want to the rds to be accessible from.  The port doesn't matter, but you can choose mysql if you like.

Comment: What if you don't want to use VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Click on EC2 in the AWS console. You'll find Security Groups under Network & Security section, in the left menu. 
Then you can go ahead to create a new group or to modify an existing one.